# How could I omit detection for some files with Java 7 WatchService

Tags: java, events, watchservice

I've registered CREATE, MODIFY and DELETE events to the monitor successfully and they works fine to me. For my issue I would like to do some file modification like 'rename' once CREATE event is triggered so MODIFY event will be triggered next as well however I don't want it. Could I just omit MODIFY event for this time?

```
 if(event.kind().equals(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE)){
                try{
                    if(!name.toString().startsWith("~")){
                            Path tempPath = Paths.get(path+"/~temp_"+name.getFileName());
                            Path oldPath = Paths.get(path+"/"+name.getFileName());
                            Files.move(oldPath, tempPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                            PDFStamp.stampPDF(tempPath.toString(), oldPath.toString());
                            omitPath.put(name, name);
                            Files.delete(tempPath);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
```

Comment: also [jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Finally I have to make a meta file to store each file's status and check/Omit when event caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to tell the watch service temporarily ignore events.  I suggest that you do it in your code.

However, what you seem to be doing here it to create a backup of a file by having the watch service notice that you've just created the new one.  But I don't think that will work.   By the time your code gets the event, the old version of the file could already have been overwritten with the new one.  And then your `move` call will move the new file to the "temp" location.

I suggest that you get the code that creating the file to make the backup of the original one *before* it opens the new one.  Your code will be simpler, more reliable and more likely to be portable.

Comment: Appriciate for your suggestion. Well what I really want is that once new file drop into the folder, some modification will take place and overrite the file at the end. What is confusing me is that a series of acitons on the file triggers different events one by one but I couldn't read out the status of the file coz the file has been modified and saved before the event is pop.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying.  However, if you want to be able to to get the status of the file *before* the modifications happen, you won't be able to do this using the watch service.  The watch service reports event after they have happened, not before they happen.

Comment: I don't need to know the status but to omit MODIFY and DELETE event while renaming

Comment: Again, you can't ... like I said in the first line of my Answer.  You have to code your application to ignore the events.

Comment: Thanks. I make it by recording actions and validation checking. But I'm still looking forward how to extract user info of the origin file. Anyway you do me a big favor thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [jpathwatch](http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com/)

It supports events like `ENTRY_RENAME_FROM` \ `TO`

Comment: Appriciate for caring, but isn't there any suggestion on nio with Java 7?